# Data is sent through Ajax request but PHP script is not receiving

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send form data to a php script, but the script is not receiving the data.
I don't understand why, Javascript should be fine php should be fine.
Testing the data right before the ajax request shows the result, but checking the POST data from server side returns empty.

This is my ajax code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'contact-mail.php',
        data: { nume: nume.value, telefon: telefon.value, email: email.value, message: message.value},
        error: function(err, status) { console.log("error contact " + err);}
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
        document.querySelectorAll(".sdc-cardboard-form input").forEach(input => {
            input.value = "";
        });

    });
    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
```

This is how I get the data in my PHP script:

```
$name = $_POST['nume'];
$name = addslashes($name);
$tel = $_POST['telefon'];
$tel = addslashes($tel);
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email = addslashes($email);
$message = $_POST['message'];
$message = addslashes($message);

echo "Server side: ".$name." ".$tel." ".$email." ".$message;
```

Echo returns only "Server side:" part.

I am using the same method to send data to server on another website.
Anyone see's any error in my code? Is there something I am missing?
Jquery 3+
PHP 7.2

Update, question. Could it be htaccess rewrite rules which would trim everything from .php onwards?

Here are my htaccess rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I haven't read much on htacess, so I am just making a guess.

Comment: Have you opened up the developer tools for your browser (F12)? Have you watched the request being made? How are you setting the values?

Comment: Check that the values are definitely being sent by scrutinising the request in the console. Then from the PHP end, run `print_r($_REQUEST)` to see what's being received. Also check you're not running foul of the `POST_MAX_SIZE` stat in your php.ini file (unlikely, given the data you seem to be sending.)

Comment: @Mitya don't use print_r for debugging, use var_dump() - for all you know, there could be a bunch of null bytes in those variables, which are invisible to print_r() but visible to var_dump()

Comment: @hanshenrik Fair point. `var_dump()` has other advantages, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I think I found the issue, could it be that the htaccess re-write rules are the issue?

Comment: Neither print_r or var_dump returns anything, just empty arrays.
Monitoring network tool from Chrome shows request having status code 302 then redirects from contact-mail.php to contact-mail .

Comment: Are you using re-write to remove the file extensions? If so change `url: 'contact-mail.php',` to `url: 'contact-mail',` Just like was done here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63191289/1011527

Comment: @JayBlanchard that worked, thank you very much. You can add as answer so I can mark it if you want. Again thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using mod-rewrite to redirect the file extensions you will need to do that in your AJAX request. Change:

```
url: 'contact-mail.php',
```

to

```
url: 'contact-mail',
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to .htaccess rewrite rules (Apache mod_rewrite : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html ) all the url for those PHP files will be update

means **example.com/test.php** will be **example.com/test**

that is why your AJAX request did not find the URL and give you an error.

`url: 'contact-mail.php'`

sould be

`url: 'contact-mail'`

please check, if this works or not. if it did not work, reply or comment.